# What is the picture folder to use in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

In my View I can drag and drop from my Content folder and get picture address automatic.

```
<div style="text-align:center">
    <img src="~/Content/information-button16.png" id="info-@car.Car_ID" />
    <img src="~/Content/center-icon.png" id="center-@car.Car_ID" />
</div>
```

Now Im trying to create a block message and want add a waiting cursor but this doesnt seem to work, because Content isnt a public folder.

```
$('#tabs').block({
    message: '<h1><img src=' 
                   + localpath  
                   + '@Url.Content("/GTracker/Content/busy.gif")' 
                   + ' /> Just a moment...</h1>',
    css: { border: '2px solid #3399ff' }
});
```

What should I do?

Comment: Is your script in a separate `.js` file or contained within a Razor view?

Comment: @haim770 Right now is on the View between `<script>` tags

Comment: @haim770 But is a Partial View, dont know if that is relevant

Comment: What's wrong with `Url.Content("~/Content/...")`? If `Content` is not a public folder then it won't be accessible anyway (and it should be a public folder).

Comment: `@Url.Content("/GTracker/Content` always use `@Url.Content("~/Content` and don't mix with `+localpath+` - have a look at the rendered html, should make it clear.

Comment: Regarding *"because Content isn't a public folder"* : If your drag+drop images do work, then your message image should also work, look at the src of each in the output html (in the browser)

Comment: The View path render as `<img src="/GTracker/Content/information-button16.png" >`

Comment: @freedomn-m I just fix it writting `'<h1><img src="/GTracker/Content/busy.gif")' + ' ` and is working is that ok or Im making an awfull sin? But obviously Isnt a public folder. You cant access `http://site/GTracker/Content/busy.gif` is only public to the application.

Comment: The `src` attribute tells your browser where to get the image, it doesn't provide the image itself - so the browser needs to access that file, so you should be able to also "access it directly", which would, as I understand your terminology, be considered a 'public folder' (and needs to be).

Comment: The reason you use `~/content` instead of `/GTracker/content` is that your base url ("/GTracker/") may change at any time and the application should still work.  Eg you might create a test version "http://site//GTracker_test/Content" and everything should still work - it won't if you've hardcoded the paths.

Comment: @freedomn-m If I use `message: '<h1><img src="~/Content/busy.gif"/>` the render url is `http://Server/GTracker/~/Content/busy.gif` and that isnt and valid floder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't seem to find a quick reference, but `~` can be used on `<img src='~/...` and in `@Url.Content("~`.  It won't work in a js literal.

If your  js is in a razor .cshtml, you can do:

```
$('#tabs').block({
    message: '<h1><img src=' 
                   + '"'
                   + '@Url.Content("~/GTracker/Content/busy.gif")' 
                   + '"'
                   + ' /> Just a moment...</h1>',
    css: { border: '2px solid #3399ff' }
});
```

or

```
$('#tabs').block({
    message: '<h1><img src="@Url.Content("~/GTracker/Content/busy.gif")" /> Just a moment...</h1>',
    css: { border: '2px solid #3399ff' }
});
```

If, instead, this code is in a .js file, you'll need to pass in the translated root path, I normally do this with something like, in _layout.cshtml:

```
<head>
    <script>var rootpath = '@Url.Content("~")';</script>
```

then you can use rootpath in your .js (assuming it's included after the above)

```
$('#tabs').block({
    message: '<h1><img src=' 
                   + '"'
                   + rootpath + '/Content/busy.gif' 
                   + '"'
                   + ' /> Just a moment...</h1>',
    css: { border: '2px solid #3399ff' }
});
```

The aleviates hardcoded paths and allows your website to move around as required.