# How reference MVC content folder in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

In my PartialView I can drag and drop from my Content folder and get picture address automatic.

```
<div style="text-align:center">
    <img src="~/Content/information-button16.png"/>
</div>
```

That Path render as `<img src="/MyProject/Content/information-button16.png"/>`

Now Im trying to create a block message and want add a waiting cursor but this doesnt seem to work, because the same code generate a different Path .

```
$('#tabs').block({
    message: '<h1><img src="~/Content/busy.gif") /> Just a moment...</h1>'
});
```

The render URL is `http://Myserver/MyProject/~/Content/busy.gif`

After ask **[yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38301733/what-is-the-picture-folder-to-use-in-javascript#38301733)** about it.  I could fix it,

```
message: '<h1><img src="/MyProject/Content/busy.gif") /> Just a moment...
```

But know is a bad idea hard code the project path in case this change.

So what is the correct way to reference the MVC path in javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Resolving the URL**

If this isn't contained within an external Javascript file, you could use the [`Url.Content()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.content(v=vs.118).aspx) helper method within MVC to resolve the appropriate absolute URL :

```
$('#tabs').block({
    message: '<h1><img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/busy.gif")" /> Just a moment...</h1>'
});
```

**Consider a CSS Approach**

Another more applicable approach might be to consider using a CSS class to set your busy animation. This will allow you to reference your image without explicitly calling the entire path of it each time :

```
.busy {
    /* This URL will need to be relative to the location of the element within your CSS */
    background: url('~/Content/busy.gif');
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    display: block;
}
```

and then just use the CSS declaration as opposed to an `<img>`tag :

```
$('#tabs').block({
    message: '<h1><i class='busy'></i> Just a moment...</h1>'
});
```

Comment: First aproach looks OK. Let me move everything to a external js and try second one too.

Answer (score 0):

put the '/' in the begin of string. no ~/ or ../

```
document.getElementById('PhotoPerson').innerHTML = 
  '<img src="/Content/Images/UnknownPerson.png" class="img-center img-responsive img-thumbnail">';
```

Comment: Please describe why your answer may solve the issue?

Comment: Ops I forgot, Only put the '/' in the begin of string. no ~/ or ../